# PyQt Set App Icon and App Name in Windows Taskbar Right-Click Menu

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I found the app icon and app name is not set in the Windows task-bar right-click menu.
I tried searching in QApplication, QGuiApplication and QCoreApplication docs, but had no luck. Can someone guide me on this?

As a comparison: left is Windows Paint, right is my app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this happen on a compiled exe or while running in prompt or IDE? What PyQt version?

Comment: Thank you, this happens when in prompt. This does NOT happen on a compiled exe (PyQt5+PyInstaller).